# Can't login to Instagram using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, instagram

I'm trying to login to Instagram using `requests` library. I succeeded using following script, however it doesn't work anymore. The password field becomes encrypted (checked the dev tools while logging in manually).

I've tried :

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
login_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'

payload = {
    'username': 'someusername',
    'password': 'somepassword',
    'enc_password': '',
    'queryParams': {},
    'optIntoOneTap': 'false'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(link)
    csrf = re.findall(r"csrf_token\":\"(.*?)\"",r.text)[0]
    r = s.post(login_url,data=payload,headers={
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "referer": "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/",
        "x-csrftoken":csrf
    })
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.url)
```

I found using dev tools:

```
username: someusername
enc_password: #PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:10:1592421027:ARpQAAm7pp/etjy2dMjVtPRdJFRPu8FAGILBRyupINxLckJ3QO0u0RLmU5NaONYK2G0jQt+78BBDBxR9nrUsufbZgR02YvR8BLcHS4uN8Gu88O2Z2mQU9AH3C0Z2NpDPpS22uqUYhxDKcYS5cA==
queryParams: {"oneTapUsers":"[\"36990119985\"]"}
optIntoOneTap: false
```

How can I login to Instagram using requests?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use authentication version `0` - plain password, no encryption:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from datetime import datetime

link = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
login_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'

time = int(datetime.now().timestamp())

payload = {
    'username': '<USERNAME HERE>',
    'enc_password': f'#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{time}:<PLAIN PASSWORD HERE>',  # <-- note the '0' - that means we want to use plain passwords
    'queryParams': {},
    'optIntoOneTap': 'false'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(link)
    csrf = re.findall(r"csrf_token\":\"(.*?)\"",r.text)[0]
    r = s.post(login_url,data=payload,headers={
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "referer": "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/",
        "x-csrftoken":csrf
    })
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.url)
    print(r.text)
```

Prints:

```
200
https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/
{"authenticated": true, "user": true, "userId": "XXXXXXXX", "oneTapPrompt": true, "reactivated": true, "status": "ok"}
```

Comment: many thanks. works great. but my question is that since we are using plain password, is it a reliable solution, or it may stop working any moment?

Comment: @Soheil It all depends on Instagram, so far they support it.

Comment: I tested your python code and works great. then when I want to replicate that request in Postman, with the same headers and body parameters, I get the following response: `{"user": false, "authenticated": false, "status": "ok"}`. its driving me crazy! is there any point in your python code except for setting the headers and body parameters correctly?!

Answer (score 5):

In order to do it, you need to do some investigation job on their javascript.

After a little research, I got that they use AES-GCM with 256 bits key length, they have some prefix of 100 bytes that I still do not know what is it, then they concatenate the password to it and encrypt the whole message `100 + len(password)`.

You can read about [AES-GCM](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html?highlight=gcm#gcm-mode), get the key, iv, and additional data from their code, and complete the job yourself.

I hope that I have helped, Good Luck :)

Answer (score 5):

The above code provided by @Andrej Kesely fails for me. but I have did some changes in the code by setting the header(user-agent and Referer) in the first get "s.get(link)" request.
If you also get the error like same as me.

```
csrf = re.findall(r"csrf_token\":\"(.*?)\"",r.text)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Then here is the solution as I have told you above.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

link = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
login_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'
userAgent= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"

time = int(datetime.now().timestamp())

payload = {
'username': '<Your_Username>',
'enc_password': f'#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{time}:<Your_Password>',
'queryParams': {},
'optIntoOneTap': 'false'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers= {"user-agent":userAgent}
    s.headers.update({"Referer":link})
    r = s.get(link)
    print(r)
    csrf = re.findall(r"csrf_token\":\"(.*?)\"",r.text)[0]
    r = s.post(login_url,data=payload,headers={
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "referer": "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/",
    "x-csrftoken":csrf
    })
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.url)
    print(r.text)
```

Please use the python3 version to run this script. otherwise you will get some more error for “formatted string literals,” and "AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timestamp'".

Run the script like this.

```
python3 <your_script_name.py>
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score -3):

You can't. Instagram encrypts the password when the request is sent. Unless you can figure out the way they encrypt it and be able to do the same with the password you're sending, you can't login to instagram with requests.